# unix shell programming - checking for numbers and letters

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm fairly new to Unix shell or bash programming.

I'm doing a project on an inventory program. I'm wondering if it is possible to check for numbers and letters within a function.

For example, I were to sell a hamburger, within the price I would only put numbers, if I were to input letters in it, how can i check that I have put letters instead of numbers in it?

Sorry if my English is bad, English is not my first language.

```
echo -n "Food :"
  read food
    echo -n "Price :"
      read price
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in multiple ways.

1. Using test with if condition:

   ```
   if [ $var -eq $var 2> /dev/null ]
   then
       ...
   fi
   ```

OR

```
    if [[ $var == +([0-9]) ]]
    then
        ## its a number
    fi
```

2. Using egrep with regex command like:

   ```
   if [[ echo $var | egrep -q '^[0-9]+$' ]]
   then
        ####...its a number...###
   fi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Allowing prices to have decimal points, this checks for valid  prices:

```
re='^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$'
[[ $price =~ $re ]] && echo "Is Valid"
```

A more complete working example, which provides and error message for bad numbers, is:

```
read -p "Enter the food name: " food
re='^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$'
while true
do
    read -p "Enter the price: " price
    [[ $price =~ $re ]] && break
    echo "  You must enter a valid number"
    echo "  Please try again"
done
echo ""
echo "The price of $food is $price"
```

The following shows the above in action:

```
$ bash script.sh
Enter the food name: Hamburger
Enter the price: a lot
  You must enter a valid number
  Please try again
Enter the price: 1.9y
  You must enter a valid number
  Please try again
Enter the price: 0.99

The price of Hamburger is 0.99
```

#### How it works

The regular expression is `^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$`.  Let's look at it one piece at a time:

- `^` matches the beginning.  This assures that no non-number characters precede the number
- `[0-9]+` matches one or more numbers
- `\.?` matches the decimal point, if there is one.
- `[0-9]*` matches numbers, if any, following the decimal point.
- `$` matches at the end of the string, assuring that there are no non-number characters following the number.

Comment: this works but if i were to add letters into it, i wouldnt get any error and still would be able to continue the next line of codes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be like:

```
read price
expression='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $price =~ $expression ]] ; then
   echo "Error: Please enter a number" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

Here, ^[0-9]+$ shows "starting(^) with a number[0-9] and continuing the same till the end($)

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do i make sure i can re-enter the price again if the echo error were to come out?